# UI thread waits for "await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false)" to finish before moving to another url

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, synchronizationcontext, configureawait

Client starts some action via button. In controller its async method: `async public Task<JsonResult> CreatePresentation` that contains line `using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))`. Lets say this line takes 10s to finish. While that is happenning client wants to go to another url inside website and clicks on that url (that view is also async meaning its `async public Task<ActionResult> BRDetails(int id)`). But asp .net does not serve him view immidiatly. Instead it awaits for `await` line to finish before serving him the view (10s).

Why does asp framework **waits** for `await` line to finish before it starts producing view for next url that client requested?

I would thought that deliving the next url should start immidiatly in second thread and waits in first for `await` to finishes because of `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Environment:

- .net framework v4.5,
- iiexpress that comes with visual studio

Here is part of code (since it's a software product I am not able to share full code):

```
        async public Task<JsonResult> CreateReportFile(int id, string email)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileName = "Report " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ".txt";
            fileName = fileName.Replace('/', '_');
            fileName = fileName.Replace(':', '_');
            var fullPath = "some path";
            var presentationTask = new Creator().CreateSomeFile("some values to pass", fileName);
            var ms = await presentationTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {
                ms.WriteTo(file);
                ms.Close();
            }

            var emailAttachment = BusinessReportsEmail.savePresentation(fullPath, fileName);
            await BusinessReportsEmail.sendEmail(emailAttachment, email).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return Json(new
            {
                Status = "ok",
                Data = email
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                Status = "error",
                Data = ex.Message
            });
        }
    }

public async Task<MemoryStream> CreateSomeFile(string programData, string outputFileName)
    {
        // Use this in production
        var url = string.Format(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["workFileUrl"]);
        var appCode = string.Format(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appCode"]);
        var appKey = string.Format(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appKey"]);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
            {
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Add("AppCode", appCode);
                request.Headers.Add("AppKey", appKey);
                var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    InputType = "json",
                    Content = programData
                });
                request.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        throw new Exception($"Failed to create {outputFileName} file.");

                    var reponseObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<FileResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(reponseObject.Content));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and than client goes to this view but needs to wait for previous call to finish.

```
    async public Task<ActionResult> ReviewDetails(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Without code I can't tell what is going on. You haven't even told us what "button" you have. WPF? WinForms? Unity3d? MVC? Blazor?

Comment: @Aron it's a MVC

Answer (score 2):

> Why does asp framework waits for await line to finish before it starts producing view for next url that client requested?

In ASP.NET, [`await` yields to the thread pool, not the HTTP client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet).

Remember, your web app is serving HTTP responses to HTTP requests. Generally speaking, a single HTTP request has a single HTTP response. Your web app can't return a response and then sometime later return *another* response. You can think of an `await` as an "asynchronous wait", and your method will asynchronously wait there, so it won't even get to the `return Json(...)` until after the `await` completes.

If you want to kick off an independent background process, then I recommend using [asynchronous messaging](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as described on my blog. It's complex, but it's necessary for reliable work. Alternatively, you could use something like a SPA and not return early at all - allow the user to change pages while the HTTP request is still in progress.

Comment: Thanks, read some of your blogs before, great stuff.

Comment: just quick follow up question. The same problem persist even if I want to open url in new tab. Why is that?

Comment: @usernumber124153: The server is still doing the `await` before returning the response. If this is in another tab, then that tab will take that long to load.